# Making SessionStorage calls using async await in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I have a functional Component that has the following code.

```
import { isUserAuthCheck } from "../../Utils/SessionStorage";

function DefaultPage({ history }) {
  useEffect(() => void (isUserAuthCheck ? history.push("/home") : null));
```

and in my Utils/SessionStorage, I have the following

```
export const isUserAuthCheck =
  sessionStorage.getItem("isUserAuthenticated") === "true";
export const getIsUserAuthenticated = sessionStorage.getItem(
  "isUserAuthenticated"
);
export const setValueInSession = (key, value) =>
  sessionStorage.setItem(key, value);

export const setIsUserAuthenticated = str =>
  sessionStorage.setItem("isUserAuthenticated", str);
```

Problem here is, `isUserAuthCheck` doesn't seem to update every time there's a change in `sessionStorage`. How can I make sure that it's getting updated every time there's a change in `sessionStorage`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not a function. It doesn't fire the checking everytime you call it. You have to make it a function to run the checking AGAIN.

```
export const isUserAuthCheck = () =>
  sessionStorage.getItem("isUserAuthenticated") === "true";
```

Or you can update it everytime you set value for `isUserAuthenticated`, but it is a `const` so you'd have to change it.

EDIT:

If you want it to be a `getter` as i mentioned:

[image]

Also avoid using `"true"` or any kind of these things. There is a reason why `bool` type is available

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue. I believe the latter is the good approach though.

Comment: I would say the first. You don't want it to be dependent on other places as that value can be replaced by any other function which can never happen if it is a function. If you want it to be an object-oriented-like approach `getter`, you can declare a getter at your `export default` so you don't have to set the value as well everytime you change your Session Value